# How to extract specific point values of a LOWESS or MOVING AVERAGE trendline to a dataframe in Plotly?

Tags: plotly, plotly-python, trendline

I would like to extract/export the individual point values of a LOWESS or Moving average trendline in Plotly to a dataframe. Is there a way to do this?

Plotly.Express.Get_trendline_results doesnt seem like it would solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can get graphing data from the [trendline examples](https://plotly.com/python/linear-fits/#locally-weighted-scatterplot-smoothing-lowess) in the references and make them into data frames. Basically, the figure created by plotly has data and layout. The above example consists of a scatter plot and a graph using the line mode of the scatter plot. the second is the trendline graph data, which is used to create a data frame by specifying the x- and y-axes. fig.data and fig.layout are stored in dictionary format, so please check them. Please check fig.data and fig.layout as the data is stored in dictionary format.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = px.data.stocks(datetimes=True)
fig = px.scatter(df, x="date", y="GOOG", trendline="lowess")

df_trendline = pd.DataFrame({'Date': fig.data[1]['x'], 'value': fig.data[1]['y']})
fig.show()
df_trendline.head()

Date    value
0   2018-01-01  0.996729
1   2018-01-08  0.997604
2   2018-01-15  0.998471
3   2018-01-22  0.999327
4   2018-01-29  1.000171
```